# Protect Static Files (.html, .css, .png, etc) with AzureAD Authentication in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, azure-active-directory, static-files

I have a .NET MVC website where the user is authenticated using AzureAD.
All the controllers are decorated with `[Authorize]` attribute.

Considering **Security**, we don't want unauthenticated users to access/download static content of the application like images, .js, .css files.

Can anyone suggest a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and successfully implemented this by using the following:

1. Add `app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);` at the end
   of `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication()`. Please refer the below code of Startup class.
2. Add below in Web.configs.

   [image]
3. Under <system.webServer> add the below

   [image]

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public Startup()
    {
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieManager = new SystemWebChunkingCookieManager(),
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                MetadataAddress = String.Format(Globals.WellKnownMetadata, Globals.TenantId, Globals.DefaultPolicy),

                ClientId = Globals.ClientId,
                RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = Globals.LogoutPostUri,

                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                },

                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile + OpenIdConnectScope.OfflineAccess,
                CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
            }
        );
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution posted by Saca pointed me in the right direction, but adding the JS to every page was not a valid solution for me. There were thousands of HTML files, lots with no common JS file I could tack that ADAL code into. I would have had to find a way to insert that JS on all those pages.

My first solution was simply creating a normal .NET MVC app with the proper auth configured. Then I simply loaded this legacy content via an iFrame. This worked but was limiting for the users.

As Fei Xue mentioned in another comment, the next solution involved scrapping the iFrame but routing all requests for static files through a controller. Using this as a reference for understanding that: https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works

The above solutions worked. However, eventually this app ended up as an Azure App Service and I simply turned on authentication at the app service level with just the pure html files